New Blower Motor will not start
I have replaced the blower motor on a Lennox G26 furnace. The old motor had Black, Red and White Leads. The replacement Motor has White, Black, Red, Yellow and Brown Leads. I have landed the new Black, Red and White Leads in their original location on the board. Power verified to the red lead on activation, but the motor will not start. Do the Brown and Yellow leads need to be landed or spliced or ?

Consult the new motor documentation. If there isn't any documentation, send it back and get one from a reputable source. Obviously whatever you got is not a direct replacement for what you had. A common possibility is that there's a need for a capacitor on the new motor that the old one did not use.

don't make an assumption that wire color is the same for the two blowers ... the original black function can easily be a different color in the new blower

Probably dead start capacitor
